# MySQL how to create a custom id column formatted with character, date and number

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT...
```

I need the sequence to go like so:

```
KR-21-001
KR-21-002
KR-21-003
```

Explanation

`KR` - Is Stable Character

`21` - Todays year date format (yy)

`001` - Increments by +1 when a new value is added.

Next year (2022)..

the sequence needs to be reset back to `001` but the 20 changes to 21 because of the year being 2022 :

```
KR-22-001
KR-22-002
KR-22-003
```

Question

How can I create this custom ID column BEFORE INSERT?

Comment: You could do this with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: Are you wanting it to be a primary key or secondary unique index? MyISAM or InnoDB? Are you using FK references?

Comment: secondary unique index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are requesting is actually somewhat more complicated.

1. You can't use auto genrated columns and for A BEFORE Trigger NEW.id is empty

As you complicate more and more you need to add a column to  grab the change i year

But you could do something like this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customers (
> id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
> ,custom_id VARCHAR(100)
> ,test varchar(10) 
> )
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customers (
> id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
> ,Newid INT
> ,created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> ,custom_id VARCHAR(100)
> ,test varchar(10) 
> )
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER after_customers_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON customers FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     SET @created := (SELECT IFNULL(created_at, NOW()) FROM customers ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1);
>     
>     IF YEAR(@created) <> YEAR(NEw.created_at) THEN
>        SET NEW.Newid :=  1;
>     ELSE
>         SET NEW.Newid := (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Newid),0) + 1 FROM customers);
>     END IF;
>     SET NEW.custom_id = CONCAT('KR_',DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%y'),'_',LPAD(NEW.Newid,3,'0'));
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO customers (test) VALUEs ('test')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO customers (test) VALUEs ('test')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE customers SET created_at = created_at - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO customers (test) VALUEs ('test')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM customers
> ```
>
> ```
> id | Newid | created_at          | custom_id | test
> -: | ----: | :------------------ | :-------- | :---
>  1 |     1 | 2020-07-30 22:10:30 | KR_21_001 | test
>  2 |     2 | 2020-07-30 22:10:30 | KR_21_002 | test
>  3 |     1 | 2021-07-30 22:10:30 | KR_21_001 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd807b475eea9acaed29e8694897aa1d)*

Comment: This is only half of his question :) , i will add second part tommorow when i had time if you don't know how to add it.

Comment: somehow i didn't see that second part the last time

Comment: @Adamszsz is there a problem?

Comment: don't think so , we need to ask creator of issue :P if there is we can try correct it.